# PromiseKit and CloudKit saving (using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, promisekit

I'm new to PromiseKit and I'm a bit confused to how to handle multiple promises. I'm using CloudKit and saving two records, and when they are both saved, I want to do something on completion and something else on error. I thought I should do the following, but Xcode is complaining so obviously I must have misunderstood:

```
let savePromise1 : PMKPromise = db.saveRecord(record1)
let savePromise2 : PMKPromise = db.saveRecord(record2)

PMKPromise.when([ savePromise1, savePromise2 ]).then() { results in
    // handle success or errors
}
```

The error I get is "Cannot convert the experssion's type '(($T8) -> ($T8) -> $T7) -> (($T8) -> ($T7) -> $T7' to type 'PMKPromise'

I don't really understand what the error means, but I was expecting "results" to be an array of (result, error) tuples.

How should I write my "when" statement instead?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: Are you using the Swift version or the Objective-C version of PromiseKit?

Comment: I was using the Pod, so the ObjC version. The Swift version didn't have the CloudKit classes. I have since heard from the developer that this problem is not solved yet, but he's working on it. So for now, no solution, but hopefully soon. :-) I'd still love some input on how to read that expression type, though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Swift version of PromiseKit, it now has CloudKit support:

```
when(db.save(record1), db.save(record2)).then { (record1, record2)->Void in

}
```

The Swift version also has a tuple-when so you don't have to sort through an array of results.